# Creating custom crontab files

Tags: cron

I would like to create my own crontab files. For example, I would like to have a folder on my server called `jobs` where I can input several files that act like crontabs. For example one file called `videos` contains all the scheduled jobs for my **videos** and another file called `channels` which contains all the scheduled jobs for my **channels**.

How can I get crontab to recognize these files as crontab files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by these commands

```
crontab /path/of/jobs/channels
crontab /path/of/jobs/videos
```

Each file's contents will be installed using these commands as a separate crontab file.

To check that the new entries have been installed properly or not, you may use the `crontab -l` to view all of your current crontab entries.